# display tag always using the last action

Tags: displaytag

I am using displaytable tag to display a table. Below is the code snippet of the same.

```
<display:table  export="false" id="admin" class="displaytag"    name="requestScope.adminConsoleForm.businessList" style="width:100%" requestURI="/adminConsole.do" pagesize="2" >
```

In the form, i enter some fields and click on save button. The data will be saved and refreshed in the page. But when i click on some other page numbers, it is again performing the save and goes to that clicked page.

Answer (score 1):

Please use ***the specific action name for the RequestURI that will be map to the specific action***.

I faced the similar problem. Please check the below link for details.

[display tag with struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359100/display-tag-with-struts2/7370723#7370723)

[display tag sorting duplicate the last action performed on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630622/display-tag-sorting-duplicate-the-last-action-performed-on-the-page)

Hope this help. Thanks.