# display tag sorting duplicate the last action performed on the page

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

I have display tag like this.

```
<display:table class="displayTable" id="orgList"
                 name="${sessionScope.organisationArray}" requestURI="" pagesize="13"
                defaultsort="1" sort="list">
          <display:column property="organisationName"
                title="Organisation Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/>
          <display:column property="description" title="Description" />
</display:table>
```

***I got the ArrayList of the data from Session.***

The problem is whenever I click to sort the Organisation Name column, it automatically performs the last action. For example, I add a new organistation, then I back to the list. And I click to sort, then adding of a new organisation perform again.

**When I check the URL on the sortable column, it is pointing to the last action (Add action ) URL. If last action is delete, it is pointing to Delete action. Second time click on sortable column is OK, it works well.**

**But just first time straight back from another action, sorting is duplication the same action. 
How can I overcome this problem?**

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Finally I fix it just by adding `requestURI="blahblah.action"` which is an action just to display all the list. 

Thanks to the following link:
http://www.coderanch.com/t/53098/Struts/display-tag-sorting-Struts

Thanks.

Comment: please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359100/display-tag-with-struts2) for detail info.

Comment: Although irrelevant to this post but I hate display tag. Its too heavy and confusing. I suggest using [dataTables](http://datatables.net/) instead. A big big fan :)

Comment: @anu thanks for the tip, I will try some day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix it just by adding `requestURI="blahblah.action"` which is an action just to display all the list.

Thanks to the following link: [coderanch.com/t/53098/Struts/display-tag-sorting-Struts](http://coderanch.com/t/53098/Struts/display-tag-sorting-Struts) Thanks.

please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359100/display-tag-with-struts2) for detail info.